# python regex split string while keeping delimiter with value

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a text file with name:value elements in it into lists with "name:value"...  Here's a twist:  The values will sometimes be multiple words or even multiple lines and the delimiters are not a fixed set of words.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to work with...

```
listing="price:44.55 name:John Doe title:Super Widget description:This widget slices, dices, and drives your kids to soccer practice\r\nIt even comes with Super Widget Mini!
```

What I want to return is...

```
["price:44.55", "name:John Doe", "title:Super Widget", "description:This widget slices, dices, and drives your kids to soccer practice\r\nIt even comes with Super Widget Mini!"]
```

Here's what I've tried so far...

```
details = re.findall(r'[\w]+:.*', post, re.DOTALL)
["price:", "44.55 name:John Doe title:Super Widget description:This widget slices, dices, and drives your kids to soccer practice\r\nIt even comes with Super Widget Mini!"]
```

Not what I want.  Or...

```
details = re.findall(r'[\w]+:.*?', post, re.DOTALL)
["price:", "name:", "title:", "description:"]
```

Not what I want.  Or...

```
details = re.split(r'([\w]+:)', post)
["", "price:", "44.55", "name:", "John Doe", "title:", "Super Widget", "description:", "This widget slices, dices, and drives your kids to soccer practice\r\nIt even comes with Super Widget Mini!"]
```

which is closer, but still no dice.  Also, I can deal with an empty list item.
So, basically, my question is how do you keep the delimiter with the values on a re.split() or how do you keep re.findall() from either being too greedy or too stingy?

Thanks ahead of time for reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a look-ahead assertion:

```
>>> re.split(r'\s(?=\w+:)', post)
['price:44.55',
 'name:John Doe',
 'title:Super Widget',
 'description:This widget slices, dices, and drives your kids to soccer practice\r\nIt even comes with Super Widget Mini!']
```

Of course, it would still fail if there are some words followed immediately by a colon in your values.

Comment: WORKED!  THANKS!  I've never understood the look-ahead or look-behind stuff very well.  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

@Pavel's answer is nicer, but you could also just merge together the results of your last attempt:

```
# kill the first empty bit
if not details[0]:
    details.pop(0)

return [a + b for a, b in zip(details[::2], details[1::2])]
```

Comment: I had thought about doing it this way, but it just seemed too cumbersome, but I appreciate the answer!